# Can't save JSON data using MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC4.5 and I'm trying to save an object in to a SQL Server Database.

My object looks like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Title",
    "value": "Test"
},{
    "name": "Description",
    "value": "Some text"        
},{
    "name": "Duration",
    "value": "15 minutes"
}]
```

The jquery AJAX is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("NewAppSave","App")',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    accept: 'appication/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    data: { model: jsonData },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            alert("Met succes !");
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

In the controller I've created the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult NewAppSave(Appointment model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var db = new MainDbContext())
        {
            var appointment = db.Appointments.Create();
            appointment.UserId = 1;
            appointment.Title = model.Title;
            appointment.Description = model.Description;
            appointment.Duration = model.Duration;
            db.Appointments.Add(appointment);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong");
    }
    return Json(model);
}
```

It looks like no data is send to the controller. What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: The object you're sending should be directly provided to `data` (ie. not in the `model` parameter) and the property names must match the `Appointment` class for the ModelBinder to work.

Comment: use this function definition - public JsonResult NewAppSave(List<Appointment> model)

Comment: In order to bind to that model your object must be `data: { Title: 'test', Description: 'Some text', Duration:'15 minutes' }`

Comment: Appointment object must have name and value property in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot you all ! With some code I managed to re-write my object to the right format.